# How to set the visibility of a Tablix based on the individual values of cells?

Tags: reporting-services

I've a table that has several columns, such as firstname, lastname, position, and so forth. There's one important column called **Rating**. In the beginning of the year, every row has the value of **Not Rated**. Then people get rated progressively.

I'd like to hide the whole table if all the column have the value Not Rated. If even a single row has a different value then the table wont be hidden.

How do I set the visibility for the **Tablix**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in the tablix visibility property:

```
=IIF(Sum(IIF(Fields!Rating.Value<>"Not Rated",1,0),"DataSetName")>0,False,True)
```

Replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of yours.

Let me know if this helps.